# DataGridView missing last row in the Excel file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, export-to-excel

So when i try to export my data on datagridview to excel, the last row in the excel file was not included, and here i used datasource to connect the ms.access database. Can you guys help ?

BtnPrint.Click

```
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"

    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlworkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlworksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misvalue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer


        xlapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue)
        xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

        For i = 0 To SKU2021DataGridView.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To SKU2021DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To SKU2021DataGridView.Columns.Count
                    xlworksheet.Cells(1, k) = SKU2021DataGridView.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlworksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = SKU2021DataGridView(j, i).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next
        xlworksheet.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        xlworkbook.Close()
        xlapp.Quit()

        releaseobject(xlapp)
        releaseobject(xlworkbook)
        releaseobject(xlworksheet)

        MessageBox.Show("Proses Export Berhasil", "Sukses", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
```

ReleaseObject()

```
Private Sub releaseobject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

[Here The Pic of The Excel and WindowForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2BCm.png)

Comment: You should `.RowCount - 1` here. No default/new row to skip here since you have DGV's `AllowUserToAddRows = False`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    For i = 0 To SKU2021DataGridView.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To SKU2021DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To SKU2021DataGridView.Columns.Count
                xlworksheet.Cells(1, k) = SKU2021DataGridView.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlworksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = SKU2021DataGridView(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

To

```
    For i = 0 To SKU2021DataGridView.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To SKU2021DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To SKU2021DataGridView.Columns.Count
                xlworksheet.Cells(1, k) = SKU2021DataGridView.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
            Next
            xlworksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = SKU2021DataGridView(j, i).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next
```